# Mongo indexes in detail

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have mongo db collection which looks like the following

```
collection {
   X: 1,
   Y: 2,
   Z: 3,
   T_update: 123,
   T_publish: 243,
   T_insert: 342
}
```

I have to create an index like

```
{X: 1, Y: 1, Z: 1, T_update: 1}
{X: 1, Y: 1, Z: 1, T_publish: 1}
{X: 1, Y: 1, Z: 1, T_insert: 1}
```

But what I see is that the value X: 1, Y:1, Z:1 will lead to redundancy and only time paramter which I intend to use for sorting is changing. Is there any better way to create the above indexes so that I do not ave to create three separate indexes.

Also say if I have index like

```
{X: 1, Y: 1, Z: 1, T_update: 1}
```

and I want Mongo to return result such that x = 5, y = any value, Z = 4, sort = T_update 
will the above index be useful or should I create an index such as

```
{X:1, Z:1, T_update: 1},
```

I hope that I can avoid it.

Comment: To answer the last part of your question (the rest was anwered by Adam); No it will not use the X, Y, Z, T_update index for an X, Z, T_update query. It always goes from left to right so if you want to leave out index fields those fields will have to be on the far right of your compound index. Note that if you sort the sort field can become part of that problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is going to depend on the selectivity of the fields you are indexing - if the criteria you will be using to filter X, Y, or Z are not very selective then they can essentially be left out (or moved to the right of the compound key).

Let's say you are using a filter like Y is not equal to 1, where 1 is a rare value.  Since you will be traversing almost the entire index to return most of the values, and scanning the data, having an index on Y will be of less benefit than having an index for the sort first.  Given that scenario, if sorting on T_Update it would probably be beneficial to have an index like: `{T_update: 1, Y : 1}`.

In the end, there are lots and lots of permutations here in terms of what might be the most efficient way to index.  The real way to figure out the best indexes for your data set is to use [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) and [hint()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Hint) to test the various indexes with your specific query pattern and data set.

Comment: Agreed, selectivity is key. Avoid adding low cardinality fields to compound indexes unless they are very selective and always order compound index fields on how selective they are whenever possible.